# Print individual checks in automatica using API

Tags: acumatica, billing

I am trying to integrate acumatica API to my application for this I need to create check then print and close the bill
I am able to process all check but not able to process individual check, help me to process single check

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend using a webhook handler

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/easily-send-post-requests-to-acumatica-using-webhooks/

1. Your system sends a POST request to the webhook URL with the payment nbr
2. In the acumatica code, you use the report writing services to print a report PDF

   ```
    // Use dependency injection to get these in a graph
    private readonly IReportLoaderService _reportLoaderService;
    private readonly IReportRenderer _reportRendererService;

    public byte[] YourMethod()
    {
            //Report Processing
            var report = _reportLoaderService.LoadReport(reportId, default);
            using var streamManager = new StreamManager();
            _reportLoaderService.InitDefaultReportParameters(report, parameters);
            _reportRendererService.Render(RenderType.FilterPdf, report, default, streamManager);
            return streamManager.MainStream.GetBytes();
   }
   ```
3. You return the report pdf as base64 as response, and update the payment status.